# Why did Newt and Jacob enter the case?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In this scene from *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, Newt and Jacob enter the case right after they catch the Erumpent.

> NEWT (O.S.): (to JACOB) In you hop.
>
> [We see the case sitting alone below the bridge.]
>
> [TINA quickly appears around the corner and hurriedly sits on the case. She closes the catches, looking shocked but determined.] 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

Why would they enter the case knowing that an Erumpent was still in there and Jacob still smelled like Erumpent musk? Plus they didn't need to enter the case at all to find the Demiguise. So why would they enter the case, leaving the case sitting alone on the bridge? I'm pretty sure they wouldn't want a Muggle picking it up.

In response to the comment below, Jacob wouldn't be of much use in containing the Erumpent to a particular area, *especially* while he smelled like Erumpent Musk.

Comment: Presumably to get the Erupment contained to an area before it caused a whole lot of damage in there

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot He could still have left Jacob outside; he wouldn't be of much use

Comment: Speculation: Maybe he wanted to keep an eye on Jacob, or because there are chances the Erumpent could have smelled the smell outside the case from inside.

Comment: @Clockwork By that point, Newt trusted Jacob, so he wouldn't need to keep an eye on him. And as for the Erumpent smelling the musk from inside, Newt (while inside) could probably work with it more easily when the smell is faint, as opposed to when the source of the smell is standing right there.

Comment: films want set pieces to show of the amazing visual effects - don't worry about the story

Comment: @NKCampbell We don't see inside the case from this point onwards until they climb out of it IIRC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Newt had to put the Erumpent in her enclosure.

Newt’s case isn’t just a giant bag of magical creatures. Each creature has a habitat in which it belongs.

> “*The perimeter of the leather case is dimly visible, but the place has swollen to the size of a small aircraft hangar. It contains what appears to be a safari park in miniature. Each of NEWT’S creatures has its own perfect, magically realised, habitat.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

It would have been very important for Newt to contain the Erumpent quickly, because a rampaging Erumpent can cause a lot of damage.

> “*NEWT and JACOB run up to the now half-empty zoo, the outer walls of which have been demolished in places. A large pile of rubble lies at the entrance.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

Therefore it was necessary that Newt go into the case at that point, before the Erumpent could cause serious damage.

#### Jacob’s smell was a useful lure with little risk.

Jacob still smelling like Erumpent musk may have actually been useful in luring the Erumpent back to her enclosure, as she would follow the source of the smell. Newt was able to keep Jacob safe in the Central Park Zoo, and Jacob being in the case wouldn’t pose any higher level of danger than was present there.

> “*The Erumpent charges towards the source of the smell, bellowing madly. JACOB wails, running as fast as he can in the opposite direction. The Erumpent gives chase – they crash through rubble and ice-ponds, before charging across the snow-covered park.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

Presumably Newt and Jacob went into the case to return the Erumpent to the proper enclosure, perhaps using the fact that Jacob smelled of musk to their benefit. When next we see the Erumpent, she is still agitated but safely back behind the walls of her enclosure.

> “*HOLD ON TINA as she looks around at the Erumpent, now stamping through her enclosure. TINA’S face is full of wonder and admiration. JACOB chuckles at her expression.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay*</sup></sub>

Newt would have gone into the case himself because it was necessary. He likely took Jacob because the smell would have been a useful lure, he trusted Jacob by then and was confident in his own abilities to keep Jacob safe while returning the Erumpent to her enclosure.

Comment: I'd agree with all of this, except that Newt and Jacob were barely able to handle the Erumpent in an open area. They only managed it by trapping it in the case. Imagine the trouble they'd have in a closed space (with a whole host of other potentially dangerous creatures around).

Comment: @Righter Well, a baboon did have Newt’s wand for part of that time, so Newt was both unable to use it and focused on retrieving it until he got it back. If he had his wand the entire time, Newt would have more control of the situation and be able to take action faster. In addition, all of Newt’s other creatures in his case would still be in their own enclosures.

Comment: Actually, Newt's method of containing the Erumpent involved him doing a mating dance,  not using any sort of spell. And we already know that some of the creatures can come loose if they want to (the Murtlap comes to mind).

Comment: @Righter Yes, but Newt was distracted by needing to retrieve his wand, so he wasn’t able to do that either. Additionally, out of all the creatures in Newt’s case, only a few came loose - the Erumpent in question, the Murtlap, the Niffler, the Occamy, and the Demiguise (who only left the case to keep watch over the Occamy). Except for the Erumpent, these are not particularly dangerous creatures.